# GNU Screen/tmux equivalent for Windows for remote text console (not GUI) connections

Tags: windows-7, terminal, tmux, console

**Short question**: is there any **terminal multiplexer that runs in a Windows CMD shell**? I suppose PowerShell could be enough too.

**Complete question**:
I have a Windows 7 SP1 on a powerful computer intended to run [OCLHashCat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/), that is an **intensive command-line number cruncher** who uses to keep **running for hours** before finishing. Due to its needs of GPU power, this program must be run on this computer with Windows 7 SP1.
When I am "on the road", I use to connect to this computer to manage such program with my portable (netbook) and through a mobile **internet line that is often very slow, expensive, and uses to disconnect unexpectedly**.
I can connect to the GUI of my Windows 7 via, for example, VNC Server, but it consumes a great bandwith, it is slow, and the screen of my portable is too small (the Win7 computer features a 32" screen, and that makes window-moving rather awkward).

So the ideal  solution would be to use only **text/terminal** transfers:

- Connect via **remote text console** (SSH, for example) to the Win7 SP1 machine.
- **Manage** OCLHashCat to start/stop/review the specific process.
- Disconnect **keeping the process running** when needed.

By working this way I will **reconnect later** to check the progress of OCLHashCat.
This is the default behavior of the classic GNU Screen in Linux.

But **there is no screen for Windows** capable of running in text mode, or I have not been clever enough to find it.
The best I have found until now is **CygWin's Screen** version, but it only runs in graphics terminal, like `mntty`.

So, my question is: is there any GNU Screen or equivalent for Windows capable of running in text mode (not GUI), so I can run OCLHashCat remotely?

I have checked:

- CygWin's Bash terminal, that runs in remote SSH sessions, but can not work with `screen`or `tmux`. They fail with a `open terminal failed: not a terminal` message.
- Any other terminal I have checked, wheter Cygwin's or Windows native (Tera Term, Babun... etc), needs GUI to start, so it can not be run from remote SSH.

I know that there is a version of OCLHashCat for Linux, but I need my powerful computer to keep Windows 7 SP1 for now.

I know about [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/643120/windows-powershell-screen-equivalent) based on PowerShell background jobs, but it does not allow me to check the progress of the remote command-line program.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) then  both `tmux` and `screen` should work. If you are able to login to a shell running bash in a cygwin environment then you should be able to start `tmux`. Being unable to find a terminal/tty suggests a possible security restriction inside your remote login shell or the server process. Have you eliminated that as a source of your error?  If you start a shell and a tmux session on the server can you `attach` to the existing session or see it running (`tmus list-sessions`) when you login remotely?

Do your security or SSH server logs show any useful message? Cygwin also includes a `sshd` server -  perhaps using that application on the server side may make management of access controls easier to isolate and debug.

Comment: `ConEmu` is too a GUI-requiring terminal. Just like the others you mention, as I told in my original question.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. You want a terminal multiplexer you can leave running on your Windows server and then connect to with a terminal application on your netbook?  To do this you would be installing tmux and screen on the server and making them accessible over SSH to console based client applications. Is this  what you want to do?

Comment: That is correct. Remote access to `tmux`, `screen` or equivalent via SSH running on my Windows 7 machine should solve my problem.

Comment: I assumed your problems were client side - but it does seem more like a server side issue. Windows user and admin security contexts are complicated when it comes to services and remote connections and these may be affecting your SSH installation. Will watch this thread and add any information I can glean. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the issue myself. I was not happy with the current solutions (making multiple ssh connections in a tabbed console).

So I made my own tool (similar to tmux).

https://github.com/osen/vimux

Dead simple, just extract and run bin/vimux.